# How to decode server response to utf-8?

Tags: http, curl, d

I get json using std.net.curl.get.

Here's the code:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.json;
import std.net.curl;

void getJson()
{
    auto url = "http://some_domain.com";
    auto client = HTTP();
    client.addRequestHeader("Authorization", "some-uuid-abra-cadabra");

    writeln(url.get(client).parseJSON);
}
```

Everything works fine, but...

Cyrillic text in the received JSON look like this:

```
{"address":"ÐÐ¾ÑÐºÐ²Ð°
```

How to decode it?

---

Here's the solution:

```
auto resp = cast(string) url.get!(HTTP, ubyte)(client);
auto json = resp.parseJSON;
```

Comment: Nit: sending a Content-Type header field in a GET request is meaningless.

Comment: @JulianReschke, it doesn't solve the problem, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Documentation says: "The template parameter T specifies the type to return. Possible values are char and ubyte to return char[] or ubyte[]. If asking for char, content will be converted from the connection character set (specified in HTTP response headers or FTP connection properties, both ISO-8859-1 by default) to UTF-8.". Could you please check which header the website return?

Comment: @user1365836 Thanks! The problem is solved by setting the type ubyte to the url.get!(HTTP, ubyte) (client). Please fill out the answer and I will mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation says:

> The template parameter T specifies the type to return. Possible values are char and ubyte to return char[] or ubyte[]. If asking for char, content will be converted from the connection character set (specified in HTTP response headers or FTP connection properties, both ISO-8859-1 by default) to UTF-8.`

So probably you should check returned http headers or you can dowload bytes and transcode them.